# Nash equilibria of simultaneous game and first/second player advantage in sequential game

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

If we compare 2-person simultaneous game and corresponding sequential game (same payoff structure, but players make their decisions one after another) it often happens that:

- If simultaneous game has several pure strategy Nash equilibria, corresponding sequential game has first player advantage (for example: Battle of sexes).
- If simultaneous game has no pure strategy Nash equilibria, corresponding sequential game has second player advantage (for example: rock-scissors-paper).

Is it always the case?
Are there any theorem with respect to the subject?